# Android: takePicture() not making sound

Tags: android, camera, default

I am using the `takePicture()` method from the `Camera` class. It takes the picture , but it makes no sound! My client wants the default click sound that Android makes.

I have seen other threads and it seems that the problem is in disabling the sound, not the opposite! Why is it that my app is not making the click sound??

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I also had this problem. I solved it by using following code:
The following is used to call takePicture:

```
clickButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(final View view) {
                mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback, null, onPicTaken);
            }
        });
```

Now shutteerCallBack:

```
private final ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
        public void onShutter() {
            AudioManager mgr = (AudioManager) getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
            mgr.playSoundEffect(AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND);
        }
    };
```

Now Do whatever after taking picture from camera:

```
     /**
     * This will be called after taking picture from camera.
     */
    final transient private PictureCallback onPicTaken = new PictureCallback() {
        /**
         * After taking picture, onPictureTaken() will be called where image
         * will be saved.
         * 
         */
        @Override
        public void onPictureTaken(final byte[] data, final Camera camera) {
         }
```

This will play sound on clicking capture button.

Thank you :)

Comment: Wow!!!! You saved my day Shrikant!! It worked!! =D Thank you so much!! =) Just one more question. I am using the Galaxy Tab 10.1 and the sound it makes on my app is not the same that the default camera app in the tablet does. Do you think Samsumg might have customized the sound for its native camera application?

Comment: Yeah might be, but seriously speaking, I am not very sure about it.

Answer (score 19):

If you want a camera to play the default android sound, you have to give it an *empty* shutter callback.

```
ShutterCallback shutterCallback = new ShutterCallback() {
    @Override
    public void onShutter() { 
        /* Empty Callbacks play a sound! */
    }
};

mCamera.takePicture(shutterCallback , null, onPicTaken);
```

Tested on HTC One SV and Samsung Galaxy XCover 2.

You give the callback an empty shutter callback and then it plays the default sound.

If you call `takePicture` with a null `ShutterCallback` the camera won't play any sound.

The answer of Shrikant is working, but might behave unexpectedly as `mgr.playSoundEffect();` is not intended to be called with `AudioManager.FLAG_PLAY_SOUND` as [the doc](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#playSoundEffect%28int%29) states.

Comment: Worked for me. Thanks @HOLLO